# Navigating to next page using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, biopython

How do I use beautiful soup to navigate through all pages of the result. For example I have to scrape this site:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed

The search query is 
"((oncology) AND breast cancer) AND resulted in"
 without the quotes.
How do I fetch all the pages? I tried looking in the form data in the request headers. Tried modifying some fields. I am able to modify it to get 200 entries per page. But no more. I actually need to iterate through pages to fetch everything. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Suppose for now, I just wanted to look at the 4th page.

Relevant portion of the code:

```
post_params = {
    'term' : val,
         'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.PageSize' : 20,
'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPageSize' : 20,
'coll_start' : 61,
'citman_count' : 20,
'citman_start' : 61,
'coll_start2' : 61,
'citman_count2' : 20,
'citman_start2' : 61,
'CollectionStartIndex': 1,
'CitationManagerStartIndex' : 1,
'CitationManagerCustomRange' : 'false',

'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.cPage' : 3,
'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage' : 4,

}

"""This part handles the scraping business"""
post_args = urllib.urlencode(post_params)
baseurl = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov'
url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url, post_args)
page = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
```

It still fetches the first page. Once this part succeeds I am thinking of iterating over this code changing the params everytime.

Comment: you should add your code

Comment: you are not able to look at `'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage' : 4` and do xrange(1, n) and using the result instead of 4??

Comment: @akira Suppose I just wanted to look at 4th page. I am not iterating currently. Just trying to fetch a page with a given page number.

Comment: you fetch one page. if you want to fetch more: fetch more. i do not understand your problem.

Comment: @akira It is not fetching the 4th page. It is still fetching the first page of the result.

Comment: then you are not using the proper post_params. click to "200 per page", watch the changed params (`EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Pubmed_DisplayBar.sPageSize:200`). go to last page, watch the output again: `EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PubMed.Pubmed_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage:8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never scrape PubMed -- there is always an easier way of retrieving data directly. Install and use the [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) package. Here is a simple script to get the first 10 papers using your query:

```
from Bio import Entrez, Medline

# Always tell NCBI who you are  
Entrez.email = "your_address@example.com"  

term="((oncology) AND breast cancer) AND resulted in"

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", retmax=10, term=term)
record = Entrez.read(handle)

print record['Count']  # see how many hits in your search

for ref in record['IdList']:
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=ref, 
                           rettype="Medline", 
                           retmode="text")
    paper = Medline.read(handle)
    # Medline returns a dict from which we can extract the 
    # fields we desire
    print '-' * 30
    print paper['TI']
    print
    print paper['AB']
```

The manual is extensive but you only need to read the section on searching and fetching records with BioPython Entrez and parsing the results with BioPython Medline.

Comment: That was great. One more thing. I just needed the abstract. How to extract it from the handle.read()

Comment: @user3286661 -- I have edited the snippet to include use of the Medline module to parse the returned records into Python dicts